# LXC vs. LXD: Which is “more secure”?

Tags: linux, lxc, container

My friend told me today that I should never use LXC without changing its default configuration. Instead, I should prefer to use LXD, as it is "more secure" by default.

Is that true? What are the differences between LXC and LXD with regard to security?

I know that LXD is a wrapper for LXC, but does it really matter which system I use in terms of "basic" features? I don't need LXD's REST API for example.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out LXD is more secure than LXC by default: https://github.com/lxc/lxd/issues/2771